# enclose variable results on single quotes

Tags: php, variables

Hello i have the following php code:

```
$singlequote = "SELECT `Email` FROM `exped_contacts_req`"; // define your SQL
$stmt = ExecuteQuery($singlequote); // execute the query
$emailtodoc = ""; // initial value
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { // check condition: if record count is greater than 0
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // begin of loop
        $emailtodoc .= $row["Email"] . ", "; // in case the result returns more than one row, separated by comma
    } // end of loop
    $emailtodoc = rtrim($emailtodoc, ", "); // don't forget to remove the last comma after loop finished
} //end of check condition`
```

right now my variable results return as:

abc@domain.com, def@domain.com

but i need this return as:

'abc@domain.com', 'def@domain.com'.

so each email enclosed on a single quote, the problem is i can't find how reach this on my code,

any idea, thanks in advance

Comment: `$row["Email"]` holds the email, you just need to add `"'"` around it by concatenation.

Comment: If you are building a CSV you should use the library for that.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:

```
$singlequote = "SELECT `Email` FROM `exped_contacts_req`"; // define your SQL
$stmt = ExecuteQuery($singlequote); // execute the query
$emailtodoc = []; // initial value
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { // check condition: if record count is greater than 0
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // begin of loop
    $emailtodoc[] = $row["Email"]; // in case the result returns more than one row, separated by comma
} // end of loop
$emailtodoc_str = implode("','",$emailtodoc); // don't forget to remove the last comma after loop finished
} //end of check condition`
```

Way2:

```
$singlequote = "SELECT `Email` FROM `exped_contacts_req`"; // define your SQL
$stmt = ExecuteQuery($singlequote); // execute the query
$emailtodoc = ""; // initial value
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { // check condition: if record count is greater than 0
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // begin of loop
    $emailtodoc .= "'".$row["Email"] . "', "; // in case the result returns more than one row, separated by comma
} // end of loop
$emailtodoc = rtrim($emailtodoc, ", "); // don't forget to remove the last comma after loop finished
} //end of check condition`
```

Comment: Thanks way2 work pretty good. i can't vote but thanks for help guys